# How to know about user id in sessions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, authentication

I have a rails app. Now I want to fetch the users id to store it into the database. But system is showing error saying that id value is nill.

How can I store the user id in a integer or string variable?

```
 def create     
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    @data=Information.all
    @num=Information.count()
    @tym=Time.now.getutc
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      @val=session[:user_id]               # is it possible to store user id in variable @val
      #redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"

      #this part is for showing the content of the information table


      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xml { render xml: @data }
      end
    else
     flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
     render "new"
    end
 end
```

Comment: Store it in Session instead of instance variable or class variable read more about them here [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)

Comment: please, paste error log...

Comment: What does User.authenticate return? if it returns a boolean value instead of a User object, it won't have an ID. Check what is stored in the variable 'user'